# Genetic Algorithms: how to implement permutation-chromosomes with less than n! valid permutations

Tags: java, graph, permutation, genetic-algorithm

I'm currently working on a genetic algorithm which I want to find (or approximate the best permutation in a directed, non-cyclic, non-state-based graph. A possible graph could look as follows:
[Example-Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwYWM.jpg)

(Note that multiple incoming Nodes mean multiple conditions. So in order to chose G, both B and F have to be chosen first)

As opposed to something like the Traveling Salesman Problem, not all nodes on my graph are connected (hence B and E), connections won't work for both directions (A->B is fine, but B->A is not possible) and there is no node I could define as a current position (meaning after going from A to B, D is still a valid option). Therefore, while searching for permutations to put through the fitness-calculation, the solution space isn't n! but much less (~145 for the example given above).
The rule for validation a permutation would be "for any node at position n, all its preconditions must be at a position less than n"

For example "A-B-D-C-E-F-H-G-I" would be a valid permutations, while "I-G-C-H-E-F-D-B-A" would be pretty much as invalid as it can get.

With this information, I could just verify any given permutation within the fitness-function and assign a value of 0, if it is  invalid. Yet, I'm hoping that with your help I can find a more efficient solution, since I'm working with graphs that can have around 300 nodes, and calculation for all the invalid possibilites would be unacceptably time consuming. So I want to design the chromosome in a way that for both randomized starting population and evolutionary operations, only valid individuals are added to any given population.

As for testing, I'm using the JGAP library for Genetic Algorithms and Genetic Programming in Java, but an implementation of this solution isn't mandatory.

Thanks a lot for you help and please forgive me for any stupid expression since I'm not a native speaker and for any stupidity within this question since I'm fairly new to genetic algorithms.

Comment: Just to help me understand better, if the solution space is so small, why are you using GA instead of brute force? Traversing these graphs sounds fast.

Comment: The graph shown just posed as an example. The real deal is a graph with the same rules but more open (more than one initial possibility and more than one dead end) and around 300 nodes, meaning there are would be 300! permutations to check for validation

Comment: 300! is only possible if the nodes are highly connected so that they can be visited in any order. How many branches typically exit a node?

Comment: Usually one or two, currently up to five. The graph isn't finished yet, so there might be nodes with more than five branches exiting at some point, but usually it will be one or two.
As for entering branches (meaning preconditions) it's usually one, occasionally two, and up to eight so far.
Currently I'm unable to tell how this is going to impact a possible solution with genetic algorithms, and while I'm thankful for every kind of input, a solution with GA is close to mandatory (since it's for my thesis and the professor kind of expects a satisfying GA-solution to at least be introduced)

Comment: Okay, I think constraining GA like this is still a research problem, while heuristic graph search is well developed, so I was still exploring that. But if it's for school, I understand you don't have much choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your graph is DAG (Directed Acyclic Graph), as you said. Also, node A that is connected to node B **must** come before the node B. This is basically the definition of [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of such graph. You just want to find such a sorting (since there can be more than one) that is *best* according to a measure of your choice.

Here is a solution I propose.

### Genotype

For each node in the graph assign a number. The numbers for these nodes are going to be the genotype. So for the graph you posted as an example, you would have 9 numbers. Let's give it some notation: `K(n)` will be the number assigned to node `n`.

### Decoding the genotype

To decode genotype (the set of numbers) into the phenotype (the sorting), follow this procedure (basically [Khan's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn.27s_algorithm) with tie-breaking):

```
input: N is a set of all nodes in the graph
S += {r | r in N && r has no incoming connections }  // a set with the root nodes
I := {n -> |predecessors(n)| | n in N}  // a mapping from the nodes to numbers, the numbers being the numbers of incoming edges to the nodes
ordering := []  // a list of nodes
while |S| > 0  // while the open set is non-empty
    n := arg min_q {K(q) | q in S}  // from the open set, select the node with the lowest assigned number (see above)
    S -= {n}  // remove the node from the open set
    ordering += n  // add the node to the ordering
    for each q in successors(n)
        I[q] -= 1  // decrease the number of incoming nodes for each successor of n
    S += {q | I[q] == 0}  // add all nodes that have no incoming edge left to S
return ordering
```

This way you **always** get a valid solution and the numbers assigned to the nodes just determine which of the number of valid solutions is going to be constructed. You can happily evolve the numbers and you will get different orderings.

The vanilla Khan's algorithm has a running time O(|E| + |V|), i.e. linear in the number of nodes plus the number of edges in the graph. Here we need to sort the set `S` so the complexity will get higher, depending on the datastructure used for `S`. If it is a heap-based priority queue, you get something like (I'm guessing now as I'm too lazy to compute/prove it) O(|E| + |V| * log |V|). You probably want to optimize this procedure as much as possible as it is going to be called **a lot**.

**Remarks**

This decoding trick is called *indirect encoding*, i.e. you evolve something that is not evaluated directly but is rather transformed to something else that is then evaluated. This has the nice benefit of always producing a valid solution, but it also has a major drawback: small change in the genotype may result in a big change in the phenotype and vice versa. This might make it hard for the genetic algorithm.

I also suggest you try other optimisation frameworks than just GA, e.g. [Simmulated annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).

Comment: That certainly does look helpful, so first of all: thanks a lot!
Just to make sure I got it: S starts as a list of root nodes, I is a list of all other nodes with information about how many edges are incoming and ordering being a possible permutation. n will be chosen from S (where all have zero incoming nodes left, so why sort it? Maybe rather shuffle it for randomness?), removed from S, added to ordering and for each node reachable from n, reduce amount of incoming edges by 1, and if it becomes zero, add it to S.
Where would I implement this? I'm guessing within the Chromosome-Type to define

Comment: @BenjaminBatt Ad ordering of ``S``: you want to search the different orderings so you must somehow decide in which order are you going to pull the nodes from ``S`` - this distinguishes the different valid orderings so that is what you want to search through. Ad implementation: I would implement it as a part of evaluation of the genotype - first you decode and then evaluate the result. And when you are finished you of course decode the best solution.

Comment: I might miss out on something there, but if I order S (like, numerically or alphabetically or something), how will I end up with different results in the ordering-list? Shouldn't it be filled the exact same way every time and therefore end up identically?

Comment: @BenjaminBatt You order the nodes by the numbers you evolve (I called them ``K(n)``, see the **Genotype** section of my answer) - that way, when you search the numbers, you search the different orderings.

Comment: I'm really sorry for still not quite getting it. So instead of A-I in my example, the Nodes would now be 1-9 (or 0-8), right?  So ordering A-I alphabetically or 1-9 numerically still always ends up with the same order. Where am I mistaken?

Comment: Gosh, I guess I've just been lacking some much required distance to that question! Within the article you linked regarding Kahn's Algorithm, it says "Depending on the order that nodes n are removed from set S, a different solution is created." So if I want (valid) solutions to differ from one another, I should either just remove nodes from S randomly or come up with a method that explicitly tries to get as many different solutions as possible. 

Now I just need to find out where exaclty to implement Kahn's Algorithm within the library I'm using.

Thanks alot, you indeed helped me big time!